# sorting mysql result datas

Tags: php, mysql

for example i have a table which looks like :

**id   | date | ...**

1. 20.07.2011
2. 20.07.2011
3. 20.07.2011
4. 20.07.2011
5. 21.07.2011
6. 21.07.2011
7. 21.07.2011
8. 21.07.2011
9. 25.07.2011
10. 25.07.2011
11. 25.07.2011
12. 25.07.2011
13. 25.07.2011
14. 25.07.2011
15. 25.07.2011
16. 31.07.2011
17. 31.07.2011
18. 31.07.2011
19. 02.08.2011
20. 02.08.2011
21. 02.08.2011
22. 02.08.2011
23. 02.08.2011
24. 02.08.2011
25. 02.08.2011
26. 02.08.2011

how i can get each date and ids for each date in easiest way ( maybe only with a query )

i need something like :

20.07.2011 {1,2,3,4}

21.07.2011 {5,6,7,8}

25.07.2011 {9,10,11,12,13,14,15}

31.07.2011 ...

02.08.2011 ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT `date`, GROUP_CONCAT(`id`) FROM `example` GROUP BY `date`
```

[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) on [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

You can append/preppend curly braces and sperate the id's how you like it. Just look at the docs.

Answer (score 0):

```
select `date`, group_concat(`id`) from `table` group by `date`
```